# Convert MongoDB Document to Extended JSON in Shell

Tags: json, mongodb, shell

I am looking for a Shell tool that can convert a mongodb document into extended JSON.

So if the original JSON file looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a8c60b8c83eaf000fb39547"),
    "name" : "myName",
    "created" : ISODate("2018-02-20T17:54:00.091Z"),
    "components" : [
        ...
```

The result would be something like this:

```
{
    "$oid" : "5a8c60b8c83eaf000fb39547",
    "name" : "myName",
    "created" : { "$date" : "2018-02-20T17:54:00.091Z"},
    "components" : [
        ...
```

Comment: if this is already `cold` JSON file and not coming from the DB you can't easily do it. No tool would know that your `"created" : ISODate("2018-02-20T17:54:00.091Z")` should be `"created" : { "$date" : "2018-02-20T17:54:00.091Z"}`. Best would be when you are running this from the DB and writing the file since there you have various JSON functions/options.

Comment: The standard command line tool for exporting in MongoDB Extended JSON format is [`mongoexport`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/), which is part of the tools included with a MongoDB server installation. There is a companion tool [`mongoimport`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport) to import from Extended JSON into MongoDB. If those aren't suitable, can you elaborate on what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

The MongoDB shell speaks Javascript, so the answer is simple: use JSON.stringify(). If your command is `db.serverStatus()`, then you can simply do this:

```
JSON.stringify(db.serverStatus())
```

This won't output the proper "strict mode" representation of each of the fields `({ "floatApprox": <number> }` instead of `{ "$numberLong": "<number>" })`, but if what you care about is getting standards-compliant JSON out, this'll do the trick.

Comment: I should have specified the input in a JSON file, not direct from DB

Comment: some thing like this                                                                                            
const EJSON = require('mongodb-extjson');
const text = '{ "int32": { "$numberInt": "10" } }';

// prints { int32: { [String: '10'] _bsontype: 'Int32', value: '10' } }
console.log(EJSON.parse(text, { relaxed: false }));

// prints { int32: 10 }
console.log(EJSON.parse(text));                                  
https://github.com/mongodb-js/mongodb-extjson